# how to filter a list only if the another list is not null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to filter a list `myList`, but only if the another list `choosenThings` is NOT null.

**Optionally:** Check if it has at least one element.

`myList` - the base list I'm filtering

`choosenThings` - list with something data

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(e -> choosenThings.contains(e.getKindId()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I do this? Is it possible to do this in filter?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (choosenThings != null) {
    // your filtering logic
}
```

If all you have is streams, everything looks like a lambda...

Comment: Thanks,  it possible to this some how in  filter? becouse i have a some code under this code i have pase here, and I don't want to duplicate it

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(e -> choosenThings == null || choosenThings.contains(e.getKindId()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why test `chosenThings`'s reference for every element in the stream? Here's a variant on @Adriaan_Koster's solution:

```java
Predicate<Element> predicate = 
    chosenThings == null ? e -> true: e -> chosenThings.contains(e);
myList.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do the null check in filter but ugly as hell:

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(e-> choosenThings != null ? choosenThings.contains(e.getKindId()) : true)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Ok thanks :)  i think it will be ok for my purposes

Comment: You might want to go with @MikeFHay's answer, which  looks slightly better than this one.